# Ubuntu can't find libcrypto.so.1.1

Tags: ubuntu-22.04

Ubuntu can't find `libcrypto.so.1.1`, yet it exists in a snap on the box:

```
instadeq@server:/opt/instadeq/instadeq-provider$ ldd ./lib/crypto-5.1.1/priv/lib/crypto.so

linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc4c329000)                                                                                                                  
**libcrypto.so.1.1 => not found**                                                                                                                              
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa8eb1aa000)                    
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa8eb412000)                                                                                              

instadeq@server:/opt/instadeq/instadeq-provider$ locate libcrypto.so.1.1                
/snap/core20/1581/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1                                                                                  
**/snap/core20/1587/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1**
```

Why?

More Info:

"apt-file search libcrypto.so.1.1" did not find the library.

Also, libcrypto.so points to a newer version of the library:

$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so                                                                                                          lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul  4 11:20 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so -> **libcrypto.so.3**

Comment: `apt install apt-file & apt-file update & apt-file search pattern` - this would lead to the correct package usually

Comment: Try just a search for `libcrypto`, the "so" and version bits can vary or might be links not captured by the package system. Older software may need legacy versions...

Comment: Searching for libcrypto yields 3000+ results, so that doesn't work. Ubuntu just can't seem to find a library stored in its own snap system.